# Sass-loader issue in production environment

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, sass, yarnpkg

I am using rails as back-end and vue.js as front-end.
Whenever I try to build an image in production it fails and throws errors. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader'

warning " > vue-loader@15.9.3" has unmet peer dependency "css-loader@*".

warning " > vue-loader@15.9.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.1.0 || ^5.0.0-0".

warning " > sass-loader@9.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.36.0 || ^5.0.0".

warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".

warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".

My log file is like this:
Anyone can help?

```
yarn install v1.19.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > vue-loader@15.9.3" has unmet peer dependency "css-loader@*".
warning " > vue-loader@15.9.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.1.0 || ^5.0.0-0".
warning " > sass-loader@9.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.36.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 8.74s.
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader' in '/opt/overwatch'
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:337:24
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at done (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2925:13)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:449:23
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:30:40
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /opt/overwatch/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/overwatch/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
resolve 'sass-loader' in '/opt/overwatch'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /opt/overwatch/package.json (relative path: .)
    resolve as module
      /opt/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /opt/overwatch/node_modules
        using description file: /opt/overwatch/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /opt/overwatch/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/sass-loader)
            no extension
              /opt/overwatch/node_modules/sass-loader doesn't exist
            .js
              /opt/overwatch/node_modules/sass-loader.js doesn't exist
            .json
              /opt/overwatch/node_modules/sass-loader.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /opt/overwatch/node_modules/sass-loader doesn't exist

The command '/bin/sh -c RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?